# Как добавить postgres в контейнер?

Tags: postgresql, docker

Разрабатываю restAPI. При написании и тестировании приложения, использовалась субд развернутая на моей системе(наверное это называется локально). Но вот я подобрался к Docker.

Я собрал Docker image моего приложения,при запуске image указал маппинг портов чобы при обращении на локальный порт, запрос перенеправлялся на порт Docker-a.

И вот, пришла пора тестировать мои API в Postman, но вместо заветного response-a я получаю ошибку, что postgres отсутствует на порту 5432. И тут я понял, что в Docker-e видимо экземпляра postgres нет вовсе, либо нужно тоже указывать маппинг postgres-a при старте.

А как же postgres настраивается на docker образе? Желаетельно подход, который будет правильным для комеерческой разработки.

Я запускаю image так:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 appname
```

UPD: Предвижу, что может понадобится редактировать dockerfile. Вот он:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.21.4

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/udonetsm/cmngb

COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o ./cmngb .
CMD ["./cmngb"]
```

UPD2:
Ну и, если быть точнее, ошибка такая:
`dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address`

UPD3: Исправлюсь, ошибка означает, что в том postgres что в контейнере отсутствует целевая база данных и пользователь.

Comment: БД обычно не разворачивают в докер контейнере на проде. А так для запуска разных сервисов вместе существует docker compose. Почитайте что это это такое. Много примеров с постгресом. Если кратко - мы управляем сразу несколькими контейнерами. В одном ваш сервис, в другом БД. И можем настраивать их взаимодействие.

Comment: @Alpensin вот уже читал перед тем как писать сюда вопрос, что не разворачивают на проде postgres в контейнере. А как же тогда делают? Не разворачивают вообще бд в контейнере? Мне нужно как то из контейнера бегать в локальную систему чтобы делать запросы в postgres? А как? Вот никак не пойму куда смотреть, чтобы с этим разобраться. Да можно пройти курс, но в курсе обычно делают очень просто и далеко от того как на проде. Хотелось бы мнение тех кто уже на проде работает с docker.

Comment: Надо исходить из проекта и ресурсов в наличии. Сколько пользователей, какой объем данных ожидается, насколько данные критичны, насколько большая нагрузка на бд. Где вы будете разворачиваться, на своих серверах или в хостинге. И там уже смотреть как конкретно для вас лучше. Если свои серверы, то бд обычно на отдельном сервере.

Comment: @Alpensin если бд на другом сервере, то доступ к ней прописывается в dockerfile или где то в папках проекта?

Comment: Данные для подключения зачастую передаются через переменные окружения. Если хост контейнера имеет доступ до этой бд, то и контейнер должен без дополнительных манипуляций.

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будет использовать Docker compose и собирать каждый сервис в своем контейнере.

И все это собирать вместе через docker-compose.yml, примерно так:

```
version: '3'

services:
  go:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: appname
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"    
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pg_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: test
      POSTGRES_USER: test-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Более актуально будет называть файл compose.yaml

Comment: Если я все пправильно понимаю, то этот подход позволяет развернуть бд в контейнере. Но мне тут со всех источников инфа поступает, что на проде так не делают и если так делать то как остальная команда получит доступ к актуальному состоянию бд в моем контейнере? Поделитесь своим опытом взаимодействия приложения в контейнере с базой которая находится на реальной машине.

Comment: Тогда какой смысле, если вы хотите ходить из Docker'a на локальную машину? Запускайте все на локальной машине и не парьтесь. Docker для этого и создавался, что бы разворачивать отдельные сервисы в контейнерах. Если хотите углубиться, то поизучайте как работать с Docker Swarm. Что бы сохранять состояние БД, нужно прописывать volumes, а вообще при разработке не принято делать это на актуальной базе данных из прода.

Comment: volumes прописываются чтобы записывалось/читалось на/из диска локальной машины а не в контейнере?

Comment: Ну, если вы разрабатываете в Docker вы код где храните? В контейнере?